# Will the depletion layer of a p-n junction stay extended after being disconnected from the circuit where it was connected under reverse bias?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronics

We know that the depletion layer/region becomes longer when a diode is connected under reverse bias in a circuit (Is my grammar correct?). Now, my question is, if we then disconnect the diode from the circuit, will the depletion region stay extended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note, I'm no electrical engineer, but a similar question was posted here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/349677/what-happened-to-depletion-region-when-biasing-is-off-after-applying-reverse-bia.

Basically, the diode behaves like a capacitor. If you isolate it from a circuit after extending the depletion zone by applying a reversed voltage, the depletion zone will stay extended (at least I learned that from the link above...).

However, I think  the depletion zone would slowly  decrease due to thermal electrons, photo-generated electrons etc.

Comment: I agree with this answer, just the "slowly" is relative. If e.g. 1N4001 diode has 15pF capacitance (at −4 V, datasheet value) and 100 pA saturation voltage (typically measured at similar condition), the voltage will drop within a fraction of second. But the discharge current will slow down significantly at very low voltages, so a trace of original depletion layer may remain for some seconds.

Comment: @domincef Many thanks for this info! I was reading somewhere that camera pixels work like this, extending depletion zone by applying a reversed voltage, then disconnect and accumulate photo-electrons during exposure and finally read out. This increases the dynamic range compared to a photodiode without reversed bias in the beginning. Do you know if that's true or did I misunderstood? (No idea where I was reading this...)

Comment: I can recognize generic CMOS operation in what you describe. (So it is true, but not surprising.) Maybe there is some clever trick to increase the dynamic range, but I know nothing about it.